# Natural Join not returning rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

i have 2 tables 
table A

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1     007    ..  ..   ..
2     006    ..  ..   ..
3     008    ..  ..   ..
```

table B

```
 col1  col7  col8 col9 many columns
    2         A    AA
    3         B    BB
```

`SELECT col2,col8,col9 FROM table A natural join table B` does not return any rows
`col1` in both table have same name,datatype and both are primary key

I also tried

```
SELECT col2,col8,col9 FROM table A natural join table B using (col1)
```

above  get #1064 error.

```
SELECT col8,col2,col9 FROM table A join table B ON A.col1=B.col1
```

above  returns the desired result.
Why does natural join not return any rows?

If I use

```
SELECT col2,col8,col9
FROM table A
JOIN table B
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I get the Following result

```
col8 col2 col9
A     007  AA
B     007  BB
A     006  AA
B     006  BB
A     008  AA
B     008  BB
```

Comment: You might have already checked this, but in case you haven't, #1064 error code usually refers to the usage of reserved words or inserting incompatible types into fields (which you're not doing) or some other syntax error in your statements: check out this link http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/database-troubleshooting/error-1064 . It could be that in your real code you're doing one of these. Could you please post the solution when you find one...

Comment: @Davit Let me check for reserved words thanks if i get solution will post it

Comment: @Davit The error has nothing to do with reserved keywords, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error, as the natural join does not need the using clause. The natural join names automatically all columns, which exists in both tables.

You have to remove the USING clause:

`SELECT col2,col8,col9 FROM table A NATURAL JOIN table B`

If you want to name the columns (and not an ON-condition), that should be used for join, you can also combine the join with the using clause.

`SELECT col2,col8,col9 FROM table A JOIN table B USING (col1)`

When you just join, without any condition, you will get a [Cross Join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join) of both tables.

Comment: SELECT col2,col8,col9 FROM table A NATURAL JOIN table B does not return any rows any idea why?

Comment: In this case you have more identical columns in both tables (and not only column 1) which do not have matching values. You can try do do a NATURAL LEFT JOIN which will will not filter your "unjoinable" results. In such a case you must use the second notion I gave you above, to do the join.

Comment: its showing as no matching column in table B but the only one common column in table A & B have same name why don`t they combine? doing natural left join show table B values as all being NULL any idea why?>

Comment: You see the NULL values, as there was no row found, which could be used for merge. Here you can find an explanation, how the LEFT JOIN is working: [Left Join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join). As 
I don't now your schema, I could only guess, sry.